# UILocalNotifcation custom fire event, or struggle on with NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer, uilocalnotification

I have a state-transition problem with NSTimer, of which I find difficult to keep track of during applicationWillResignActive / applicationDidEnterBackground, according to the context of my app.

I was wondering if it might not be a better idea to utilise UILocalNotification, especially given it's background/inactive firing.  However, I wanted to know whether we have the ability to provide a custom method to UILocalNotification, of which does not present a dialog box (would damage the whole point of my app).  In effect, i'd like to only make use of the timer-fire capabilities of UILocalNotification, and handle the fire event with my own method which does something very "undialog-friendly"

Have checked the ADC docs and it alludes to the dialog being presented every time.

Any advice you can give on this would be appreciated.

thanks

sc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog box is presented when your app is in the background. But it is *not* presented when your app is running - instead your app is free to deal with the notification however it sees fit. So it would be perfectly possible to hook it up to a custom method of your own making.

The main reason for this behaviour is a user may not want to go into your app if it's in the background. Of course, with iOS 5 the notification may not be a dialog box - it could be one of the new notification styles.